# ubuntu will not boot after installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot

After installing Ubuntu and creating dual boot with windows. when i choose Ubuntu in the boot menu i get this message with this three rows:

```
/dev/sda6:clean, 57370/11739136 files, 1073630/46932992 blocks

[   14.714349] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A

[   14.714349] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun.
```

and the system gets stuck.

Ubuntu runs on recovery mode.

Comment: Do a web search for "pch fifo underrun" and you'll find all sorts of stuff.